# What do the square brackets and numbers mean in Lua's documentation?

Tags: lua, manual

What does the `[x, y, z]` section mean in the Lua docs? You see it on every C function.

For example, [lua_gettop](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.4/manual.html#lua_gettop) says:

> int lua_gettop (lua_State *L);
>
> [-0, +0, –]
>
> Returns the index of the top element in the stack. Because indices start at 1, this result is equal to the number of elements in the stack; in particular, 0 means an empty stack.

What does `[-0, +0, –]` mean?

Answer (score 3):

The `[-0, +0, –]` section tells you how that function manipulates the [Lua argument stack](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.4/manual.html#4.1). There's an explanation in the [Functions and Types section](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.4/manual.html#4.6), but their wall of text is a bit hard to parse. I'll summarize.

Given:

```
[-o, +p, x]
```

Those elements mean:

- `o`: how many elements the function **pops** from the stack.

  - mnemonic: `-` because it reduces the size of the stack.
  - -0 means it pops nothing.
- `p`: how many elements the function **pushes** onto the stack.

  - mnemonic: `+` because it increases the size of the stack.
  - +0 means it pushes nothing.
  - Any function always pushes its results *after* popping its arguments.
- the form `x|y` means the function can push or pop `x` or `y` elements, depending on the situation;
- `?` means that we cannot know how many elements the function pops/pushes by looking only at its arguments. (For instance, they may depend on what is in the stack.)
- `x`: whether the function may raise **errors**:

  - `-` means the function never raises any error;
  - `m` means the function may raise only out-of-memory errors;
  - `v` means the function may raise the errors explained in the text;
  - `e` means the function can run arbitrary Lua code, either directly or through metamethods, and therefore may raise any errors.